# Employee Login and logout Time need to be Compared with schedule IN and Out Time and if any shortfall that need to be add in another field in excel

Tags: excel

Sorry I am new to this and this is my first query on this forum as you have suggested I have rephrased my question hop this will  help you in understanding.

What I want to do is I want to calculate employee’s short time they have not spent in the office in excel.

Every Employee gets 240 Minutes as grace time for a month.

I get data in excel for employees Log IN and Log OUT time.

Different Employees have Different Log IN and Log OUT time.

How I want to do is  I want to compare each employee login and Logout time with their schedule IN and OUT time.

For e.g. If employee Schedule Log IN time is 09.00 AM and if he Logs IN before 9.00AM then its ok but if he logs IN after 09.00 AM then we need to find the difference in  time, let’s say he Logged IN at 09.04 AM so we have to add these 0.04  in his short time field.

Similarly If employee Schedule Log Out time is 6.30 PM and if he Logs OUT after 6.30PM then its ok but if he logs OUT before 6.30PM then we need to find the difference in time, let’s say he Logged OUT at 5.24PM so we have to add these 1.06  in his short time field.

His Short time field will have total of 0.04+1.06 =1.10 for that day.

Sum of Short time Field for the month is Added in Total Late time and if it exceed 240 Minutes then we have to mark that field in different color so HR can take action.

I need formula to calculate this I have tried few things but they are not working .

Like IF(Log IN time  Schedule Log OUT time , 0 , Schedule Log OUT time  - Log OUT time)

It works fine if they are coming late but it’s not working if they come early or goes early.

***Excel Table:***

[image]

Comment: You may want to spell check your question and put in some punctuation. It is really hard to read. Please don't put the onus on the reader to work out what's going on in your head. That is what grammar, spelling and punctuation have been invented for, so please do YOUR work. Also, please learn how to post just the part of the screenshot you want to post and not a square foot of white space. Edit your question and make these changes. Again, please read this: Edit your question and make these changes. Then help may not be too far away. And please learn the difference between "their" and "there"

Comment: Please reconsider your layout.  I don't know enough about how this is originally created but surely an Access database with calculated fields would have been better? For the above, a flat file format would have been better.

Comment: Thanks @teylyn I will be more care full in future I have rephrased my question as you suggested